# Распаралелить тесты (Cucumber 5, Junit 5)

Tags: junit, cucumber, parallel

использую Cucumber 5, Junit 5. Написал тесты в feature-файлах.

Хотел бы теперь сделать так:

- разбить тесты на несколько групп (например 2 группы: группа1 и
  группа2).
- указать для групп разные конфигурации (например: тесты из группы1 в последовательном режиме, тесты из группы2 в параллельном режиме).
- и в итоге запускать все тесты (т.е. группа1 отработает последовательно, группа2 параллельно).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать на Cucumber 5, Junit 5 ?